# HTML Control Array in JavaScript - Checkbox array of 1 returns zero length

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox, zero

I'm using a control array of checkboxes to capture a multiple selection

The following code, with two checkboxes, works well and returns a value of **2** as expected (or however many are there).

However if there is only one checkbox item in the array, it returns a length of **0 (zero)**.... why is this? Shouldn't it return a length of 1?

I have tried this in Internet Explorer and Chrome with the same results.  As a work around I am having to include a hidden bogus checkbox in the array to make sure there is always two or more items when I run the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function categoryOnClick() {
            var selectedRows = document.searchForm.elements['categorySelect[]'];
            alert(selectedRows.length);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="searchForm" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="categorySelect[]" id="1" onclick="categoryOnClick();"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="categorySelect[]" id="2" onclick="categoryOnClick();"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code that returns 0 (zero) length...

```
<form name="searchForm" action="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="categorySelect[]" id="1" onclick="categoryOnClick();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByName` to get element by `name` attribute + you want to get the checked checkboxes? so you should check the `checked` attribute too, see my answer :)

Comment: an id can not be numeric!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eKgHv/)**

```
function categoryOnClick() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByName('categorySelect[]');
    var selectedRows = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (rows[i].checked) {
            selectedRows.push(rows[i]);
        }
    }

    alert(selectedRows.length);
}
```

Comment: That's crazy code and it works - is this a bug with arrays?  it doesn't answer my question but I can certainly use the code for now.  Why does rows.length work in your example yet selectedRows.length does not in mine (I'm not interested in which checkboxes are selected at the moment)

Comment: For instance I want to say something like this **if (selectedRows.length > 0) doSomething();** where I am looking at the total number of checkboxes in the array not just checked items

Comment: @Patrick In the above code I give the checked checkbox length, however you can use `rows.length` as it will get you the total number of checkboxes, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKgHv/1/).

Comment: thanks much appreciated... still scratching my head over the different in syntax **document.getElementsByName** and **document.searchForm.elements[]**

Comment: @Patrick `elements` is an array which holds all form elements, I think you are using it in a wrong way, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKgHv/2/) and this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can do

```
function categoryOnClick() {
    var count = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").length;
    var checkedElements = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        checkedElements = checkedElements + parseInt((document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")[i].checked) ? 1 : 0);    
    }
    alert(checkedElements);
}
```

and in jquery :

```
function categoryOnClick() {           
    alert($('input:checked').length)
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery:

```
function categoryOnClickjQuery() {
    var selectedRows = $('form input').attr('name', 'categorySelect[]');
    alert(selectedRows.length);
}
```